# Excluding Ip Address from redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, ip-address

I have a custom landing page I would like to use for my website. Everyone who visits my website is redirected to For2dayprinting/for2day.html. How ever when I'm Editing my Wordpress I am also redirected to the landing page. Is there a plugin or code anyone could recommend for me to exclude my IP?

Answer (score 0):

via PHP by below code will return your own IP,

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

you can check and exclude your own IP   from redirecting functionality.